# Jetpack Compose testing: how to test colors?

Tags: android, testing, android-jetpack-compose

I have a custom Compose component that renders a user, with different borders and background colours based on that user's state.

Recently a bug was introduced in this code, so naturally I'm adding a test to verify that the correct colours are used. But have hit a brick wall trying to actually verify the colour; it seems like the only way to check it is either by capturing an image and comparing against that (which seems insane) or by adding a semantics property for the colour (which seems to not be what semantics properties are, not to mention the fact that it introduces duplication of code that could easily result in tests that pass while the actual behaviour fails...)

Is there any easy and good way to check that the correct colours are set (backgroundColor and borderColor on the modifier...)

Answer (score 0):

You should make your code be testable, and decoupling the code from UI layer. i will show you the example below:

```
   class User {
        String name ;
        int role;

        public User(String name, int role) {
            this.name = name;
            this.role = role;
        }

        UserThemeProfile getThemeProfile() {
            // your logic of background color , border color
            if ( this.role == 1 ) {
                return new UserThemeProfile(Color.BLACK, Color.WHITE);
            }
            return new UserThemeProfile(Color.RED, Color.RED);
        }
    }


    class UserThemeProfile {
        final int bgColor ;
        final int borderColor ;

        public UserThemeProfile(int bgColor, int borderColor) {
            this.bgColor = bgColor;
            this.borderColor = borderColor;
        }
    }

   
    // YOUR TESTCASE
    @Test
    public void testUserColor() {
        User user1 = new User("Mr. Mike", 1);
        UserThemeProfile themeProfile = user1.getThemeProfile();
        assertEquals(Color.BLACK, themeProfile.bgColor);
        assertEquals(Color.WHITE, themeProfile.borderColor);

        User user2 = new User("Mr. Smith", 2);
        UserThemeProfile themeProfile2 = user2.getThemeProfile();
        assertEquals(Color.RED, themeProfile2.bgColor);
        assertEquals(Color.RED, themeProfile2.borderColor);
    }
```

Comment: A pure data object being responsible for deciding aspects of its rendering on a particular page is certainly one option. Doing something similar in the UI layer isn't a bad shout, but isn't easily testable from a higher level - when testing the UI layer I'd expect to be able to test not just whether components are displayed, but what their properties are. Otherwise I'm always at the mercy of the integration between my colour calculation layer and the rendering (which is actually what led to the bug I'm now trying to test).